# How can I get IntelliSense to display a type alias instead of a union of strings?

Tags: typescript, intellisense

My issue is how types are displayed with IntelliSense, I need IntelliSense to give priority to the alias type instead of the union of strings.

In this example the type of `el` should be `T`, but instead it gives `"a" | "b"`

```
//this does not work:
const o = {a:"a", b:"b"};
type T = keyof typeof o;
const v: T[] = ["a"];
const el = v[0];

//this works:
type T2 = "a" | "b";
const v2: T2[] = ["a"];
const el2 = v2[0];
```

Is there any way to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: `"a" | "b"` *is*  `t` [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCMF4YG8CGAuARAD0wGhgCMsBPTAXwG4BYAKChIAcBTGWJAa2ZJADM2mzPnBq0A9GJhSAegH46oSLABu6NgG0AuohjrMqTJtGLoMZgBsdy9QAYjQA)

Comment: `t` is `"a" | "b"` and `v` is an array of `t`, therefore `el` could be either `"a"` or `"b"`. Do you think that `el` should be inferred to be `"a"` because you're accessing the first element of `v`?

Comment: this definitely should be t, because otherwise I am loosing type information. I am working on big permission module and it is very important to have correct naming. The same issue not happens when initial type is enum and is not created from js object.

Comment: @GeorgeChokhonelidze - what type information are you loosing?

Comment: I have 200 permissions (strings) that I am extracting from object. Same strings with different chunks are grouped and named accordingly with type name. But later intellisense shows this type as strings and that is not convenient. I'd like to see name of these chunks instead of 200 strings.

Comment: Extend your demo not with 200 strings, but with a meaningful set so that anyone can help

Comment: IntelliSense displaying a big union vs an alias name is not "losing type information", those types are equivalent.  Could you [edit] the question to make it very clear that your issue is one of how types are displayed with IntelliSense, and not the actual types (which are the same).  I'm happy to do it if you want.  (Pls mention @jcalz to notify me if you reply)

Comment: Assuming I understand your goal, the only way I know how to accomplish this is to add indirection until the compiler decides that the alias name is the best way to represent the type.  See [this Playground link](https://tsplay.dev/Wkkd0W) for example.  If that fully addresses your question I can write up an answer. If not, what am I missing? (again, pls mention @jcalz to notify me if you reply)

Comment: I went for a [mapped type](https://tsplay.dev/WvGdAw), which works, but `keyof typeof & {}` is *way* shorter!

Comment: I've edited the title to match the question, and changed `type t = ` to `type T = ` to be more conventional.  Hope that's okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The types `T` and `"a" | "b"` are equivalent, and it is essentially up to the discretion of the compiler which form to display in IntelliSense.  It could choose `T`, or `"a" | "b"`, or `keyof typeof o`, or `"b" | "a" | "a" | "b" | "a" | "a"` or `Exclude<"c" | "r" | "a" | "b", "c" | "r">` or anything else as long as it's equivalent. The compiler uses heuristics to make its decisions, imperfectly predicting which forms are most likely to be what developers want to see. These predictions are imperfect both because the compiler is not as intelligent as the developers it's trying to please, and because different developers will disagree about which forms are desirable.  Someone might come along and *prefer* `"a" | "b"` to `T` in your code example.

Anyway, every once in a while the IntelliSense type display heuristics are adjusted in an attempt to make people happier. For example, see the support added for ["smarter" type alias preservation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/overview.html#smarter-type-alias-preservation) in TypeScript 4.2, along with its implementation at [microsoft/TypeScript#42149](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/42149) and [microsoft/TypeScript#42284](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/42284).

It looks like when you add some indirection in the form of a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) or [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types), the heuristics tend to favor an alias name instead of expanding out the type definition fully.  Finding a union or intersection that doesn't change the type but also doesn't get immediately reduced to the original representation is a little tricky, you can't write `keyof typeof o | never` or `keyof typeof o & never`, because those get aggressively reduced to `keyof typeof o` which displays as `"a" | "b"` and not `T`.

One way that currently seems to work (as of TS4.8) is to intersect with `{}`, the empty object type (which also reduces, but not immediately):

```
const o = {a:"a", b:"b"};
type T = (keyof typeof o & {});
const v: T[] = ["a"];
const el = v[0];
// const el: T // <-- displays as T and not "a" | "b"
```

I can't guarantee that this will *always* work, since again, this is up to the discretion of the compiler and the possibly-changing heuristics in future versions of the language.  (This caveat applies a lot of TypeScript code, since the whole language does change fairly rapidly.)

But for now it behaves as you like.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBCMF4YG8CGAuARKzAaGARlgZgL4DcAsAFBQCeADgKYwAqiMAFANZN0gAzGPWaC4MAGQpSASirVQkWADd0bANoBdDuuyZN8xdBhMANh2XqADAZp3qQA)